# MySQL ordering table merging rows with same value on a field, but maintaining mutual order

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a MySQL table that I want to sort based on an alphanumeric field that in some cases can be overlapped. I tried several queries, I always get close, but don't reach the goal.

My table is:

```
TABLE
Sizes
COLUMN
ScaleCode   varchar(6)
SizeIndex   smallint(6) 
SizeName    varchar(30)
PRIMARY KEY
ScaleCode, SizeIndex
```

Data:

```
+-----------+-----------+----------+
| ScaleCode | SizeIndex | SizeName |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
| 00001     | 1         | 13       |
| 00001     | 2         | 14       |
| 00001     | 3         | 15       |
| 00002     | 1         | 14       |
| 00002     | 2         | 15       |
| 00002     | 3         | 16       |
| 00002     | 4         | 17       |
| 00002     | 5         | 18       |
| 00002     | 6         | 19       |
| 00002     | 7         | 20       |
| 00003     | 1         | 18       |
| 00003     | 2         | 19       |
| 00003     | 3         | 20       |
| 00003     | 4         | 21       |
| 00003     | 5         | 22       |
| 00004     | 1         | ONE_SIZE |
| 00005     | 1         | 2S       |
| 00005     | 2         | S        |
| 00005     | 3         | M        |
| 00005     | 4         | L        |
| 00005     | 5         | 2L       |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

My goal is to execute a select on SizeName with following result:

```
+----------+
| SizeName |
+----------+
| ONE_SIZE |
| 2S       |
| S        |
| M        |
| L        |
| 2L       |
| 13       |
| 14       |
| 15       |
| 16       |
| 17       |
| 18       |
| 19       |
| 20       |
| 21       |
| 22       |
+----------+
```

So, I need overlapping SizeName values shown only once, as for example 14 and 15 both available in ScaleCode 00001 and 000002 or 18, 19, 20 both available in ScaleCode 00002 and 00003.
The tricky thing is that SizeName values are alphanumeric, so I need to maintain the mutual order inside the same scale code, i.e. '2S' and '2L' must have the same order with other sizes of their own scale and not sorted as number.

What I tried is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SizeName  
FROM Sizes 
ORDER BY SizeName, ScaleCode, SizeIndex
```

but:

```
+----------+
| SizeName |
+----------+
| 2L       |
| 2S       |
| 13       |
| 14       |
| 15       |
| 16       |
| 17       |
| 18       |
| 19       |
| 20       |
| 21       |
| 22       |
| L        |
| M        |
| ONE_SIZE |
| S        |
+----------+
```

That's not what I expected, because the order inside ScaleCode 00005 is not maintained.
So, I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SizeName  
FROM Sizes 
ORDER BY SizeName + 0, ScaleCode, SizeIndex
```

but:

```
+----------+
| SizeName |
+----------+
| S        |
| M        |
| L        |
| ONE_SIZE |
| 2L       |
| 2S       |
| 13       |
| 14       |
| 15       |
| 16       |
| 17       |
| 18       |
| 19       |
| 20       |
| 21       |
| 22       |
+----------+
```

That it would be good, if only '2L' and '2S' could not be considered number.

**UPDATE:**
ONE_SIZE can be everywhere, but not inside other scales.
So, it can be before or after the scale "2S, S, M, L, 2L" but not between.
I need to maintain consistent the scale.

Thanks in advance to everyone who wants to help me.

Comment: How do we know where to put 'one_size'? What's the rule?

Comment: @Strawberry sorry, I missed it! It can be everywhere, but not inside other scales. Now, I update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a bit intricated, but I come to this solution:

```
SELECT sz.SizeName FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT IF(
  (SELECT COUNT(p1.SizeName)
   FROM Sizes p1
   WHERE p1.SizeName NOT REGEXP '^[0-9]+[\\.\\,]?[0-9]*$' AND p1.SizeName = pt.SizeName) >
  (SELECT COUNT(p2.SizeName)
   FROM Sizes p2
   WHERE p2.SizeName REGEXP '^[0-9]+[\\.\\,]?[0-9]*$' AND p2.SizeName = pt.SizeName),
   CONCAT('text', pt.SizeName), pt.SizeName) AS sortable, pt.SizeName 
FROM Sizes pt) AS sz
```

Result:

```
+----------+
| SizeName |
+----------+
| 13       |
| 14       |
| 15       |
| 16       |
| 17       |
| 18       |
| 19       |
| 20       |
| 21       |
| 22       |
| ONE_SIZE |
| 2S       |
| S        |
| M        |
| L        |
| 2L       |
+----------|
```

In this way I'm able to maintain mutual order and merge overlapping sizes.
I know it's not so elegant, ma it's the best solution I can find until know.
Comments or other answers are welcomes.

Comment: This doesn't look like what was requested - but hey, what do I know?

Comment: @Strawberry, you're right that is not the same, but what I wrote on my question was simply an example of one of the desired results. The goal was to get a column where I have all sizes with mutual order guaranteed, merging overlapping sizes. And that's what I got! So, my answer is fine to me, but I don't accept it, because I think it can be improved and probably someone else has a better (and more elegant) solution for me. Anyway, thank you for your interest!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to do a “GROUP BY SizeName” with “MIN()” around “ScaleCode” and “ScaleIndex”. After that you can order it properly